# Grid with two rows and scrollviewers

Tags: wpf, layout

I would like to have Grid with two rows. Rows should take only space needed for them (thats why Grid VerticalAlignment is set to Top). When there is not enough space to show both rows scrollbars should appear. I have tried different combinations with Auto, *, MinHeight etc. but without success.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="388" Width="525" FontSize="25">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Border Height="100" Background="Red" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="4"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Border Background="Green" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="1" />
                    <TextBlock Text="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="4"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="6"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="7"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="8"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="9"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT** Check this image. Why there is not 4 in first row, why there is empty space at bottom.
[image]

Comment: You solution works, scrollbars appear when there's not enough space. They do not appear simultanously because their content is different. What exactly do you want, for them to always appear at the same time?

Comment: See my updated answer.  I hope this is what you expected.

Comment: See edited question. There is no scrollbar at 1st row and empty space at bottom which I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Border Height="100" Background="Red" >
```

`Height="100"` makes the content in the 1st row no.4 to hide inside.  Also, you have made the rows in to two equal parts, however the content is not equal which leaves empty space at the bottom of the window.

Comment: This add one scrollviewer around all. I would like to have two scrollviewers each in one row

Comment: @kurin123 . . see the updated answer. Still you are not clear on what you want to achieve

Comment: I would like to have grid (or other control) with two rows. Rows will grow in height until theirs content will be clipped, than scrollbars will be shown. Lets say space for grid is 500px, 1st row content is 400px and 2nd row content is 600px. So first row will 200px with scrollbars and 2nd will be 300px with scrollbars. Contect in 1st and 2nd row is dynamic so I cant set 2*, 3* for grid rows during desing, they have to be adjusted  in runtime.

Comment: You are right with Height=100, it is not supposed to be there, it is copy paste error from one of my attempts

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution out of the box, because it depends on what ratio you want between the two scrollviewers, in my example I choose 50/50:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Canvas x:Name="OverallCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid x:Name="OverallGrid" Width="{Binding ElementName=OverallCanvas, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroll1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Control1" Background="Red">
                <TextBlock Text="1.1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="1.2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="1.3"/>
                <TextBlock Text="1.4"/>
                <TextBlock Text="1.5"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroll2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel x:Name="Control2" Background="Green">
                <TextBlock Text="2.1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2.2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2.3"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2.4"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2.5"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2.6"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2.7"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2.8"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2.9"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2.10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
        Control1.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
        Control2.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateScrollHeight();
    }

    private void UpdateScrollHeight()
    {
        double overallHeight = OverallCanvas.ActualHeight;
        double c1Height = Control1.ActualHeight + Control1.Margin.Top + Control1.Margin.Bottom;
        double c2Height = Control2.ActualHeight + Control2.Margin.Top + Control2.Margin.Bottom;

        if (overallHeight - c1Height - c2Height < 0)
        {
            double halfHeight = overallHeight / 2;
            double c1Additional = Math.Max(0, halfHeight - c2Height);
            double c2Additional = Math.Max(0, halfHeight - c1Height);
            Scroll1.MaxHeight = halfHeight + c1Additional;
            Scroll2.MaxHeight = halfHeight + c2Additional;
        }
        else
        {
            Scroll1.MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
            Scroll2.MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
        }
    }
}
```

I only used the canvas to measure the size available inside the window, this could be done differently as well ...